# Does opening the windows increase the rate at which a floor dries?

Tags: thermodynamics

After my mom mopped the house, she insisted me to open the window doors, so as to allow the floor to dry faster. This was at late evening time, so I told her there was no point as there was no sun to heat the room, because the temperature of the room and the temperature from outside were equal.

However, she argued back saying that the moisture inside would evaporate more, as existing moisture would go outside. A simplified image would be the following:

[image]

I quickly caught on she was basically describing the idea of **Le Châtelier's principle**. I had nothing to rebute with, so I opened the window.

But, I still feel confused since this conversation occurred. Does the principle really holds when there is no energy as form of heat to evaporate the water? This energy would be brought if both parts were not in thermal equilibrium, but in this case, they are.

Comment: Consider the relative humidity inside (and how it changes as the floor dries), and outside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many students use the [Le Chatelier's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Chatelier%27s_principle) (note the spelling) as a magic wand, applying it on everything.

The principle is also called the *Equilibrium law*. But evaporation is not an equilibrium state, it is a process. Additionally, at the same temperature, there is not even an equilibrium shift of saturated vapor pressure.

Opening the windows at balanced indoor and outdoor temperature has these major effects:

- Horizontal air flow along the wet surface disturbs the air boundary layer of high humidity at the floor, what accelerates vapor transport and therefore evaporation too.
- Exchanging indoor and outdoor air masses decreases indoor absolute (g/m3) and relative (%) humidity (increased by evaporation), what accelerate the kinetic rate of evaporation.
- As evaporation cools down the surface and air, bringing outdoor air helps decreasing this temperature drop what accelerates evaporation too.

Comment: " evaporation is not an equilibrium state". Absolutely critical

Answer (score 2):

When a liquid boils its vapour pressure becomes equal to atmospheric pressure at the boiling temperature and the vapour at one atmosphere is in equilibrium with the liquid and $\Delta G =0$ which means that $0=\Delta H-T\Delta S$. The entropy change is  $\Delta S=\Delta H/T_B$. For water this is $\approx 109$ J/mol/K as $\Delta H = 40.7$ kJ/mol. (btw. $\Delta S$ is larger than  many other liquids due to hydrogen bonding)

To spontaneously evaporate we suppose that the free energy must be slightly negative  then

$$\displaystyle\Delta G =\Delta H-T\Delta S\\ \text{small neg} =  +40700 - 300\Delta S$$

which produces a value $\Delta S \approx 136$ J/mol/K which means that for the process

$$\displaystyle \ce{H2O}\text{ (liq, 1 atm 300K)}\to \ce{H2O}\text{ (vapr in air 1atm, 300 K)}$$

the entropy change must be larger than $136$ J/mol/K. This value can be achieved but only if a sufficiently dilute vapour is produced, ($\Delta S=nR\ln(V_2/V_1),\; V_2\gg V_1$) by opening the windows and letting dry air into and moist air out of the room.

( Evaporation cools the liquid, so damp clothes can freeze on a washing line in winter. In very dry and warm climates evaporation could be used to produce ice)

Comment: Hm, using TD to compare two rates is not a typical case.